# PreRun / PreRunE hooks not being executed in cobra

Tags: go, go-cobra

I have a `cobra` command

```
var mycommandCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "mycommand",
    PersistentPreRunE: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) error {
        viper.BindPFlags(cmd.Flags())
```

and a subcommand

```
var mysubcommandCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "mysubcommand",
    Args:  cobra.ExactArgs(1),
    PreRun: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        fmt.Println("HELLO")
    },
    RunE: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) error {
        viper.BindPFlags(cmd.Flags())
```

However I don't see the `PreRun` hook being executed when there is an error in terms of argument passing.

In the case above, `mysubcommand` requires exactly one argument, so when invoking it without it:

```
go run main.go mycommand mysubcommand

Error: accepts 1 arg(s), received 0
Usage:
  myprog mycommand mysubcommand [flags]
```

FWIW what I am trying to do is to print a more elegant and informative message in case the argument count is wrong.

Same is the situation when using `PreRunE` in the place of `PreRun`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand working with the library so far is that, there is a validation done before execution of `PreRun` hooks. Since you have mentioned `Args:  cobra.ExactArgs(1)`, the validation fails causing the error.
[Docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/spf13/cobra#ExactArgs). 
If you want to handle this by yourself, you should do something like this in your `mysubcommandCmd`

```golang
var mysubcommandCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "mysubcommand",
    PreRunE: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        if len(args) != 1 {
            return errors.New("more elegant and informative message")
        }
        fmt.Println("HELLO")
        return nil
    },
```